# How to prevent jQueryUI Autocomplete's default keyboard interactions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete, keyboard-events

I'd specifically like to prevent the interaction when I push ENTER to prevent jQueryUI Autocomplete from selecting the currently focused item and closing the menu.

I'm referring to the following documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

The principle is the same. Just change the `setTimeout` function to submit your form instead (as demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/X8Ghc/8/)

**UPDATE:**

You are correct, `$(this)` was supposed to refer to the `ui-menu` (and obviously didn't). The new fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/X8Ghc/7/, works reasonably well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        "open": function(e, ui) {
            //using the 'open' event to capture the originally typed text
            var self = $(this),
                val = self.val();
            //saving original search term in 'data'.
            self.data('searchTerm', val);
        },
        "select": function(e, ui) {
            var self = $(this),
                keyPressed = e.keyCode,
                keyWasEnter = e.keyCode === 13,
                useSelection = true,
                val = self.data('searchTerm');
            if (keyPressed) {
                if (keyWasEnter) {
                    useSelection = false;
                    e.preventDefault();
                    window.setTimeout(function() {
                        //since there is apparently no way to prevent this
                        //contemptible menu from closing, re-open the menu
                        //using the original search term after this handler
                        //finishes executing (using 'setTimeout' with a delay
                        //of 0 milliseconds).
                        self.val(val);
                        self.autocomplete('search', val);
                    }, 0);
                }
            }
            return useSelection;
        },
        "source": ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"]
    });
});​
```

**Original:**

This works in [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X8Ghc/1/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        "select": function(e, ui) {
            var keyPressed = e.keyCode,
                keyWasEnter = e.keyCode === 13,
                useSelection = true;
            console.log(e);
            if (keyPressed) {
                if (keyWasEnter) {
                    useSelection = false;
                    $(this).open(e, ui);
                }
            }
            return useSelection;
        },
        "source": ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"]
    });
});​
```

Comment: hmm, when I cut and paste your `select:function()` into my app i'm getting the following error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'open'`. What is `$(this)`? Shouldn't it refer to the `ui-menu` whereas I think mine is referring to the `$('#autocomplete')`

Comment: @timpeterson: Sorry about that... :) Updated answer and fiddle.

Comment: thanks for the correction. Sorry I think I wasn't clear. What I don't want is for hitting return to "select the currently focused item". I want hitting return to submit the form posting whatever is in the input box (not what is selected in the ui-menu). I'm less interested in whether the ui-menu is open or not. I keep getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined` located in jQuery.autocomplete.js.

Comment: -@pete, line 186 in jquery.autocomplete.js is what's causing the problem. I've made a gist where I've commented this line out: https://gist.github.com/3964869

Comment: @timpeterson: Updated answer (and fiddle).